# regex use to trim character

Tags: regex, trim

I have below text:

`Abcde-fgh-13-abcd`

`Abcdefgh-ijk-40-abcd`

`Efghijkklala-560-efgh`

i want to use regex so that the output will look like below:

`Abcde-fgh`

`Abcdefgh-ijk`

`Efghijkklala`

is it possible?

Comment: Please indicate which language/tool you are working in

Comment: I use vim text editor. i want to trim all char after -number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Vim command `:%s/-\d.*//g` to remove parts of string starting from first occurrence of `-` followed by digit.

[More](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/vim-search-replace#search-and-replace-using-the-substitute-command) on haw to replace in Vim.

Answer (score 0):

`^(.*)-\d*-[a-z]*`

https://regex101.com/r/IrWDOz/1

```js
const regex = /^(.*)-\d*-[a-z]*/gm;

// Alternative syntax using RegExp constructor
// const regex = new RegExp('^(.*)-\\d*-[a-z]*', 'gm')

const str = `Abcde-fgh-13-abcd

Abcdefgh-ijk-40-abcd

Efghijkklala-560-efgh

`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```